# Why does .append() replace table rows when sorting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

Could someone please explain why the .append() method replaces table rows when sorting.

Why doesn't it add the sorted rows to the end of the unsorted rows?

[Script](http://javascriptbook.com/code/c12/js/sort-table.js)

[Demo](http://javascriptbook.com/code/c12/sort-table.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`$.fn.append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method of jquery is based on native [`Node.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) method. This method inserts node to the end of the parent element it was called on, if new node is not yet in DOM tree. Or otherwise it *moves* node to new location. So it takes it from where it was previously and inserts to the end of the new parent.

Answer (score 1):

It does append the row to the end, but since a row can't be in two places at once, it removes it from where ever it was before.

If the sort algorithm would put the first row last then it would:

1. Remove the first row
2. Cause the next four rows to move up
3. Put the previously first row at the end